# App Store and Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I run 10.8.5 on one of my Macs, because some of the software I use doesn't seem to get on well with Mavericks.

Is there any way of stopping App Store from repeatedly asking me to update to Mavericks? In general I appreciate the update suggestions from App Store, but not this one.

Answer (score 4):

You could *purchase* (for want of a better word) Mavericks from the app store, and just pause the download, or let it download and then bin the installer (you can get it back later).